# Low-cost airline

Tags: air-travel, europe, airlines, asia, low-cost-carriers

Is there a low-cost airline between South-Asia (or the Middle East) and Europe? I don't mind changing flights and staying overnight. I want to know if there are some. I know about Scoot, Norwegian to South-Asia; Pegasus to the Middle East.

Comment: Note that "low-cost" refers to a business model, not necessarily fares. I am often able to find lower fares on, say, American or United than on jetBlue or Southwest, albeit with a great many more restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to narrow this down a bit. In general "low cost" airlines are NOT always cheaper than "full service" airlines. You need to look at specific dates and destinations to optimize the price. For example, Frankfurt <-> Bangkok in February on Etihad or Turkish is around US $600 round trip. Given the distance, I doubt you can get it a lot cheaper than that.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed relatively(in comparison to Emirates, Qatar, Oman) inexpensive flights offered by Gulf air with regional (national) carriers of European countries. However they tend to have extremely long layovers.